# Ajax image using jquery form.js

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am working with this piece of code. Here I am using jQuery, [Jquery form.js](http://malsup.github.io/jquery.form.js), and jQueryUI. The task is to upload an image in the upload folder and store the path of the image along with its position which is set by users (jQueryUI draggable is used for this). It works just fine. But I don't know exactly how it works.

Can anyone explain to me how we are grabbing the dragged position set by users and how the whole thing is working all together. If you need to see the PHP script I can share thattoo. Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /* Uploading Profile BackGround Image */
    $('body').on('change', '#bgphotoimg', function () {
        $("#bgimageform").ajaxForm({
            target: '#timelineBackground',
            beforeSubmit: function () {},
            success: function () {

                $("#timelineShade").hide();
                $("#bgimageform").hide();
            },
            error: function () {
            }
        }).submit();
    });

    /* Banner position drag */
    $("body").on('mouseover', '.headerimage', function () {
        var y1 = $('#timelineBackground').height();
        var y2 = $('.headerimage').height();
        $(this).draggable({
            scroll: false,
            axis: "y",
            drag: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.position.top >= 0) {
                    ui.position.top = 0;
                } else if (ui.position.top <= y1 - y2) {
                    ui.position.top = y1 - y2;
                }
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {}
        });
    });

    /* Bannert Position Save*/
    $("body").on('click', '.bgSave', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var p = $("#timelineBGload").attr("style");
        var Y = p.split("top:");
        var Z = Y[1].split(";");
        var dataString = 'position=' + Z[0];
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "image_saveBG_ajax_bg.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function () {},
            success: function (html) {
                if (html) {
                    $(".bgImage").fadeOut('slow');
                    $(".bgSave").fadeOut('slow');
                    $("#timelineShade").fadeIn("slow");
                    $("#timelineBGload").removeClass("headerimage");
                    $("#timelineBGload").css({
                        'margin-top': html
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("body").on('click', '.bgSave', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var p = $("#timelineBGload").attr("style");
    var Y = p.split("top:");
    var Z = Y[1].split(";");
    var dataString = 'position=' + `Z`[0];
```

You are getting the position here just before the ajax post to the PHP script, it is crudely getting the 'top' CSS attribute from the inline style on #timelineBGload element.

If you inspect the DOM when dragging #timelineBGload UIDraggable updates the top (and left) as you move it around

Comment: can you explain me again just these:                                                          var Y =p.split("top:");
var Z=Y[1].split(";");
var dataString ='position='+Z[0];

Comment: Y; splits the style attribute into two using "top:", Z splits the second element into two using ";" then you are left with the first element in Z being Xpx e.g. 100px if you've dragged it that much. A better way to get the top is just simply p.css('top');